# How to import module to service code in Python?

Tags: ros, rospy, rosservices

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, everyone!
I'm writing a ROS service for my robot in Python. I have one file which contains all code in arm_mover.py . The code has become too big and I need to replace a part to another module helpers.comm. But I don't understand how I must import my new module to the main script. Lines like 'import helpers.comm' or 'import package_name.helpers.comm' don't work.

```
/package_root
 |--/scripts
 |   |-----arm_mover.py
 |--/src
     |-----/helpers
           |--__init__.py
           |--comm.py
```

Thanks, for help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91546/how-to-import-module-to-service-code-in-python?/) by [flipback](https://answers.ros.org/users/7831/flipback/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-10-17**:
You got that `import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('my_package')` line in your script?

**Comment by [flipback](https://answers.ros.org/users/7831/flipback/) on 2013-10-21**:
At first not, but I tried it out. It didn't help =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found a decision by myself. But it's not so elegant:

```
path = os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../src/"
sys.path.append(path)
```

Maybe someone has a more pretty idea.

---

Originally posted by [flipback](https://answers.ros.org/users/7831/flipback/) with karma: 16 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2013-10-21**:
You could add imports for the needed classes/... in the **init**.py file, but again that is now a clean way